# Why does my team keep getting mismatched?

Tags: fifa-12

I made a new team, arranged it and started to search for prey. The Match-up screen matched my 1,5 * team with a 5 * team with 100 chemistry. I was like: "lol, nice one EA ^^ " I tried to match up again, same results.

Every team I got matched up against was either 4 or 5 * with 100 chem.

What happened and what can I do to play against teams such as mine again?

Comment: I edited your title in hopes that you will get more visitors. A FIFA 12: Confusion could be a number of different things. If you feel my edit is inappropriate feel free to switch it back. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try playing the tournament which has a "maximum of 3 stars" entry requirement for teams (I think it's called Best of the Rest).

You'll still often come up against teams with 100% chemistry being controlled by players with god-like skills, but you should also be able to get some good matches in there too.

Comment: but i want to be able to "choose" my opponent! What can i do??

Comment: If everyone could choose their opponent for ranked games, everyone would only choose players with worse ratings than them.  No game does this.